# Automate Slicer to Hide and Show Rows in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, show-hide, slicers

I have a pivot table with a slicer and I want to link it to hide or show certain rows based on the slicer selection. The code I have works now for doing that but when there is no slicer selection, I want all those hidden rows to be visible again and that's the part I'm stuck on. Currently when nothing is selected in the slicer, all the rows are hidden, which is the opposite of what I want. Please help!

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

 Dim cell as Range

If Target.Name <> "PivotTable1" Then
Exit Sub
Else

    For Each cell In Sheet2.Range("A2:A25")
        If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Item").SlicerItems("Pen").Selected = True And cell.Value = "East" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Item").SlicerItems("Pencil").Selected = True And cell.Value = "Central" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Item").SlicerItems("Pen").Selected = True And cell.Value = "Central" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Item").SlicerItems("Pencil").Selected = True And cell.Value = "East" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Item").SlicerItems("Pen").Selected = False And ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Item").SlicerItems("Pencil").Selected = False And cell.Value = "East" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If

    Next
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim SLC As SlicerCache
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim rngU(1 To 2) As Range
    
    If Target.Name <> "PivotTable1" Then Exit Sub

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set SLC = Wb.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Item")

    Set rngDB = Sheet2.Range("a2:a25")
    For Each rng In rngDB
        If rng = "Central" Then
            If rngU(1) Is Nothing Then
                Set rngU(1) = rng
            Else
                Set rngU(1) = Union(rngU(1), rng)
            End If
        ElseIf rng = "East" Then
             If rngU(2) Is Nothing Then
                Set rngU(2) = rng
            Else
                Set rngU(2) = Union(rngU(2), rng)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If SLC.SlicerItems("Pen").Selected = True And SLC.SlicerItems("Pencil").Selected = True Then
        rngU(1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        rngU(2).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf SLC.SlicerItems("Pen").Selected = True Then
        rngU(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        rngU(2).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf SLC.SlicerItems("Pencil").Selected = True Then
        rngU(1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        rngU(2).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```